How to fix tdr delay error?
I have Awesome miner installed with all pre-requisites. I have my wallet details entered. I have also entered the AM program as an exception to Windows Defender. Every time I start the miner it starts and then stops again. I get the Windows tdr delay value is missing error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Apparently

Windows tdr delay value is missing or invalid - there is a file windows_tdr registry file in the TRM folder, run it. That will fix it

Maybe that is applicable to your situation?
If not, maybe it is worth contacting AM support
